# lines with matches as a new column

Tags: python, for-loop, line

I have a file:

```
Position1
Val1
Val2
Val3
Position2
Val4
Val10
Val5
Position3
Val20
Val200
```

and I would like to move the line with the word "Position" as a new column, tab separated:

```
Val1\tPosition1
Val2\tPosition1
Val3\tPosition1
Val4\tPosition2
Val10\tPosition2
Val5\tPosition2
Val20\tPosition3
Val200\tPosition3
```

Val vary in quantity, so Position(s) have different amount of Val. I am happy to make it in python or unix shell

Comment: Is the real data actually using the words Val and Position?

Comment: Thanks. Only Position. “Val” changes to different strings. I will correct it

Comment: How should be structured the output? The same as your redirected to std::out is sufficient or you need to reuse it in further scenario that will need some format? Your title imply columns do you expect a CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the lines in your file, saving the position string when you find it and outputting a new line otherwise:

```py
pos = ''
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('Position'):
        pos = line
        continue
    print(f'{line}\t{pos}')
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Val1    Position1
Val2    Position1
Val3    Position1
Val4    Position2
Val10   Position2
Val5    Position2
Val20   Position3
Val200  Position3
```

Comment: This solution is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
with open('aa.txt', 'r') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
position_index = []
positions_values = {}
for i, j in enumerate(lines, start=0):
    if 'Position' in j:
        position_index.append(i)

for k in position_index:
    positions_values[lines[k]] = lines[k+1: k+4]

for position, vals in positions_values.items():
    position = position.replace('\n', '')
    for v in vals:
        v = v.replace('\n', '')
        print(v, '\t', position)
```